# How to investigate requests per second that are coming in?

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

If I have a server that is running Nginx + Passenger (mod_rails) how would I figure out how many requests a second are coming in?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your favorite monitoring system monitor [nginx's status](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule) or just spot-check it yourself for a snapshot of what's going on now.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for your first suggestion? And out of curiosity can you explain the second suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Also if I don't have the ability to recompile nginx to enable nginx's stub status is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Use the monitoring system you have now. If you don't have one, you probably need to drop everything and set one up. (Note that Stack Exchange sites really don't do product recommendations.) As for the second one, just load the status page in your browser and look at it.

Comment: If you can't reconfigure nginx, you need to talk to the person who can.